# android widget click event

Tags: android, widget, android-appwidget

I am trying to create app widget that create WiFi hot spot and I have problem with the click event.

I have the button and I can't use onclicklistener. 
I searched in google and here, and I understand that I need to send Intent to other class that analyzes it, but I have problem with this.

this is my MainActivity code:
http://pastebin.com/pjhLkXGh

this is my wifiWidget code:
http://pastebin.com/4NyT3U5u

and my xml file is:
http://pastebin.com/9cUuRLbB

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It'd been much easier for developers to do stuff with their widgets through using objects instead of PendingIntents. It can be quite tricky if you are coding it for the first time.

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

 public static String WIDGET_BUTTON = "com.anbe.turboandroid.WIDGET_BUTTON";
 private static final String SYNC_CLICKED    = "automaticWidgetSyncButtonClick";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews;

        ComponentName watchWidget;

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Cache, getPendingSelfIntent(context, SYNC_CLICKED));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        if (SYNC_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

            final RemoteViews remoteViews;
            ComponentName watchWidget;

            remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);                

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);

            // DO SOME STUFF HERE

            }
        }

    protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
        intent.setAction(action);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    }
}
```

You can write your tasks in the commented part.

Cheers
  Gabriel

Comment: thank you Gabriel I trying your code:http://pastebin.com/6uDPyuWx and it's cant work